# undefined method `email_verification' for UserMailer:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

Getting this error even though `email_verification` does not exist in our codebase. Here's the stack trace:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `email_verification' for UserMailer:Class
  from action_mailer/base.rb:582:in `method_missing'
  from action_mailer/delivery_job.rb:16:in `public_send'
  from action_mailer/delivery_job.rb:16:in `perform'
  from active_job/execution.rb:39:in `block in perform_now'
  from active_support/callbacks.rb:109:in `block in run_callbacks'
  from raven/integrations/rails/active_job.rb:18:in `capture_and_reraise_with_sentry'
  from raven/integrations/rails/active_job.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in included'
  from active_support/callbacks.rb:118:in `instance_exec'
  from active_support/callbacks.rb:118:in `block in run_callbacks'
  from new_relic/agent/instrumentation/active_job.rb:53:in `perform'
  from new_relic/agent/instrumentation/active_job.rb:23:in `block (4 levels) in <main>'
  from active_support/callbacks.rb:118:in `instance_exec'
  from active_support/callbacks.rb:118:in `block in run_callbacks'
  from i18n.rb:313:in `with_locale'
  from active_job/translation.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Translation>'
  from active_support/callbacks.rb:118:in `instance_exec'
  from active_support/callbacks.rb:118:in `block in run_callbacks'
  from active_job/logging.rb:26:in `block (4 levels) in <module:Logging>'
  from active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `block in instrument'
  from active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:23:in `instrument'
  from active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
  from active_job/logging.rb:25:in `block (3 levels) in <module:Logging>'
  from active_job/logging.rb:46:in `block in tag_logger'
  from active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `block in tagged'
  from active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
  from active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `tagged'
  from active_job/logging.rb:46:in `tag_logger'
  from active_job/logging.rb:22:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Logging>'
  from active_support/callbacks.rb:118:in `instance_exec'
  from active_support/callbacks.rb:118:in `block in run_callbacks'
  from active_support/callbacks.rb:136:in `run_callbacks'
  from active_job/execution.rb:38:in `perform_now'
  from active_job/execution.rb:24:in `block in execute'
  from active_support/callbacks.rb:109:in `block in run_callbacks'
  from active_job/railtie.rb:28:in `block (4 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
  from active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:87:in `wrap'
  from active_support/reloader.rb:73:in `block in wrap'
  from active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:83:in `wrap'
  from active_support/reloader.rb:72:in `wrap'
  from active_job/railtie.rb:27:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
  from active_support/callbacks.rb:118:in `instance_exec'
  from active_support/callbacks.rb:118:in `block in run_callbacks'
  from active_support/callbacks.rb:136:in `run_callbacks'
  from active_job/execution.rb:22:in `execute'
  from active_job/queue_adapters/sidekiq_adapter.rb:42:in `perform'
  from sidekiq/processor.rb:192:in `execute_job'
  from sidekiq/processor.rb:165:in `block (2 levels) in process'
  from sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:128:in `block in invoke'
  from new_relic/agent/instrumentation/sidekiq.rb:33:in `block in call'
  from new_relic/agent/instrumentation/controller_instrumentation.rb:376:in `perform_action_with_newrelic_trace'
  from new_relic/agent/instrumentation/sidekiq.rb:29:in `call'
  from sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:130:in `block in invoke'
  from raven/integrations/sidekiq.rb:9:in `call'
  from sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:130:in `block in invoke'
  from sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:133:in `invoke'
  from sidekiq/processor.rb:164:in `block in process'
  from sidekiq/processor.rb:137:in `block (6 levels) in dispatch'
  from sidekiq/job_retry.rb:109:in `local'
  from sidekiq/processor.rb:136:in `block (5 levels) in dispatch'
  from sidekiq/rails.rb:43:in `block in call'
  from active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:87:in `wrap'
  from active_support/reloader.rb:73:in `block in wrap'
  from active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:87:in `wrap'
  from active_support/reloader.rb:72:in `wrap'
  from sidekiq/rails.rb:42:in `call'
  from sidekiq/processor.rb:132:in `block (4 levels) in dispatch'
  from sidekiq/processor.rb:250:in `stats'
  from sidekiq/processor.rb:127:in `block (3 levels) in dispatch'
  from sidekiq/job_logger.rb:8:in `call'
  from sidekiq/processor.rb:126:in `block (2 levels) in dispatch'
  from sidekiq/job_retry.rb:74:in `global'
  from sidekiq/processor.rb:125:in `block in dispatch'
  from sidekiq/logging.rb:48:in `with_context'
  from sidekiq/logging.rb:42:in `with_job_hash_context'
  from sidekiq/processor.rb:124:in `dispatch'
  from sidekiq/processor.rb:163:in `process'
  from sidekiq/processor.rb:83:in `process_one'
  from sidekiq/processor.rb:71:in `run'
  from sidekiq/util.rb:16:in `watchdog'
  from sidekiq/util.rb:25:in `block in safe_thread'
```

Unresolved Rails issue: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/40607

Comment: We are going to need to see some code the stacktrace in not going to cut it in this instance. As the rails team mentioned this seems to be an application layer issue not a framework issue which means somewhere somehow "email_verification" is being called from your application layer or an included gem. Is it possible your mailer action is supposed to be called "email_verfication" e.g. is `UserMailer.email_verification.deliver_now` what is actually being called?

Comment: Are you using devise? That's one of the more general gems I can think of that "interacts" with the mailer and also can be customized with i18n as Eileen said on github

Comment: Yes we are @Clara Good catch! I'll look into that.